# Voice activation

Tags: ios, audio

I'm looking for a way to let the phone listen to the environment and when the user speaks or screams I like to react to that in my app. I guess I need to analyze the audio and have some threshold level that triggers the event.

My guess there are plenty of samples for this, but I'm not sure of the correct terms so I don't find anything relevant when Googling.

Comment: you need to listen to voice from your app right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to spider1983's answer I found this great tutorial that does what I need after some tweaking. Thanks!

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Open Ears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/). That's one of the best 3rd party libraries for these kinds of task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to set the threshold of your recoreder i was using AVAudiorecorder

```
inputPower = [aRecoreder averagePowerForChannel:0];
if (inputPower > threshold ) {

   [aRecoreder record];
} 
else if (inputPower < threshold )
{
  //Do something

}
```

Comment: This sounds like what I want. I'll look more att AVAudioRecorder and do some tests. Thanks!